# Equation $\,\ N^d\pm 1\ =\,\ p_m\cdot\ldots\cdot p_n$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

**Notation:** $\ p_0=2,\ p_1=3,\ p_2=5, \ldots\ $ -- the increasing sequence of all primes.

(The following questions, once I've formulated them, remind me of Chebyshev). A very special case of a power $\pm 1\ $ would be $\ N^2-1 = p_m\cdot p_{m+1}\ $ -- a product of two prime twins. In general, let $\ m\in\mathbb Z_{\ge 0}\ $ and $\ d\ n\ N\in\mathbb N_{\ge 2}\ $ be such that $\ m<n.\ $ Finally, let

$$ N^d\pm 1\,\ =\,\ \prod_{k=m}^n p_k $$

Then primes $\ p_m\ \ldots\ p_n\ $ are called teammates, and $\ N^d\ $ is called a $\ (-1)$-container or $\ (+1)$-container depending on $\pm,\ $ or it can be called simply container. Also, $\ s:=n-m+1\ $ is called the team's size.

**Example:** Equation
$$ 10^3+1 = 7\cdot 11\cdot 13 $$
presents a $(+1)$-container $\ 1000,\ $ for a size $\ 3\ $ team $\ 7\ 11\ 13.$

**QUESTION:**   are there infinitely many teams of sizes $\ > 2\,?$

> It'd be great to have any of the implicit questions answered too (*I'll skip the routine task of asking them unless requested*).

---

**EDIT:**   let $\ m\in\mathbb Z_{\ge 0}\ $ and $\ d\ n\ N\,\ r\ M \in\mathbb N_{\ge 2}\ $ be such that $\ m<n.\ $ Finally, let

$$ N^d\pm 1\,\ =\,\ M^r\cdot\prod_{k=m}^n p_k $$

Then, following @GerryMyerson suggestive example, the sequence of consecutive primes $\ p_m\ldots p_n\ $ is called a GeMy near miss. Now we can ask about the infinitude of near misses (in addition to teams).

Comment: Here's a size 4 near miss: $18^4-1=13\times17\times19\times25$.

Comment: +1 and :-) too.

Comment: Suddenly, I wonder about the English "a near miss". Shouldn't it be "a near hit"? (Hmmm, one can defend either of these phrases).

Comment: $1729=12^3+1=7×13×19=p_4p_6p_8$. So, it is an example of a more general case, where primes are in arithmetic progression $N^d±1=\prod\limits_{k=1}^{l}p_{m+ak}$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I am terribly sorry for that frustrating (to me) misspelling!!!!!!

Comment: @AlapanDas, nice, +1. #### There are also questions about related polynomials (I mean them as still devoted to the same number-theoretical questions; I don't mean to deviate away).